# What is the official resignation date when the registered post was delivered on time, but when to a collection point

Tags: legal-terms, germany, notice

I quit on 25th February and sent a letter (tracking with signature) to the HR department since my contract says that the resignation should be in written format.

The letter could not be delivered but the recipient was notified to collect it from a nearby post office.

But the HR denies receiving it on 28th of February, saying I do not have your letter on my table and today is already 1st of March and we will consider resignation from the 1st of March instead of February. The end date for resigning in March compared to February will be one month longer, since the notice period starts the month after my official resignation.

I have sent it on February end and if the HR has not received it on time even after notifying then how is it my mistake? Why should I serve a longer notice period?

**Please throw some light on this on how it can be dealt with or is it legally accepted**
I also have snapshot of the DHL tracking says the recipient is notified on 28th Feb.

**Does the notice to the recipient to pick up the post count as delivered?**

I had to send it on Friday since I received my next company offer letter on 25th and wanted to review the letter before resigning. Yes, I know it could be very tricky to be delivered the next day but my luck it was notified to pickup on Monday. I had to send by post because the HR sits in a different state and can be sent only by post. I have a chance to negotiate with my manager but wanted to get some Insights before I could do it.

Comment: You already asked this on [workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183123/what-is-the-official-date-of-resignation-when-registered-mail-was-delivered-on-t). Are you hoping for a different answer here?

Comment: What does your contract say regarding notice period? Typically it's a couple weeks to the end of a month. 1st of March is still within such a period. What do you mean that HR office is in another state? Is it in Germany?

Comment: Regarding DHL tracking - they could still claim the letter didn't contain the resignation.

Comment: Did DHL notify them of the letter on the 28th or deliver the letter to them on 28th?

Comment: @doneal24 I asked the same question in Workplace but I did not get the answer if the notification is considered as delivered or not.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler My contract says "Notice period of 3months effective from end of a month"

Comment: @JoeW DHL notified on 28th Feb. I had a call with HR on March 1st. I also informed it is notified to you and it should be picked up from the collection station. Even till now it's not picked up

Comment: You are saying that DHL doesn't actually deliver the letter and the person has to pick it up? If that is the case I don't see how anyone can count DHL notifying them of something as them receiving it. Sounds like you should have gone with someone that would have actually delivered the letter.

Comment: @JoeW since it's a post(tracked with signature) The postman delivers to the recipient if available in order to get a signature or will send it to you a collection point

Comment: If it isn't delivered sounds like they get it when they pick it up which wasn't the day they got notified.

Answer (score 5):

A declaration of intent among absent people becomes effective as soon as it reaches the recipient, [§ 130 Ⅰ 1 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p0396).
To reach the recipient means the declaration of intent must

- under normal circumstances (e. g. not on statutory holidays),
- get *into* the “territory” of the recipient (for example a mailbox), and
- be physically available and intelligible (e. g. readable script [no water/rain damage]).

Note, it is *not* necessary that the recipient actually *reads* your letter, but it must be *possible*.
Generally, it is presumed you check your mailbox at least once a day, so mail is considered to be delivered the next (business) day unless it arrived/was opened earlier.
Ultimately, *if* it matters, you’ll need to *prove* when your declaration of intent reached the recipient.

> I have sent it on February end and if the HR has not received it on time even after notifying then how is it my mistake?

It is *your* risk who you entrust with delivery.
It is not the recipient’s fault if *you* chose an untrustworthy or too slow carrier.

> Why should I serve a longer notice period?

Because you *signed* the employment contract.
Seriously, your employer has a *protected* interest to *trust* in you fulfilling *your* part of the agreement.
Business *needs* a certain level of predictability, so they can organize a replacement employee.

If they don’t need or “don’t like” you, you can still ask to be dismissed earlier via a mutual *Aufhebungsvertrag*, [§ 311 Ⅰ BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p1013).

> Does the notice to the recipient to pick up the post count as delivered?

No, a notification about registered mail being available for pickup is *not* a substitute for *your* declaration of intent.
Again, it must be *possible* for the recipient to identify the message.

Comment: That's why "Einwurfeinschreiben" is superior to a normal "Einschreiben" in this case: it is delivered to the mailbox and the postal service gives the date of the delivery.

Answer (score 1):

### It was received when it was received

You used a private courier (DHL) so while they have the letter it is legally the same as if you had it since they are your agent. So, you delivered it to them when it passed from DHL to the employer - 1 March 2022.

If you had used the post office the analysis would be different.

One can only wonder why you didn’t use email.

Comment: Resignation notices aren't valid in electronic form in Germany: it **has** to be a written and signed document.

Comment: @Trish how quaint. Does it also have to be handwritten or is printing allowed?

Comment: @DaleM: Written form for notice to quit, [§ 623 MC 1 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p2626). Written form, [§ 126 Ⅰ BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p0373), can be printed but needs to be signed by hand. (In contrast to that, compare [§ 2247 Ⅰ BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p7456).)

Comment: DHL is actually owned by German postal service "Deutsche Post"

Comment: @BernhardDöbler yes, but it isn’t the post office, it’s a separate company

Comment: Fun fact: in U.S. Tax Court, the government is deemed to have notice of filings when the are delivered to the U.S. Post Office, now by regulation and originally on the theory that the U.S. Post Office was an agent or instrumentality of the U.S. government.

Comment: @ohwilleke that sounds like a formalization of the postal rule in contract law that says an offer is accepted the second the acceptance is posted.

Comment: @DaleM Why should there be a difference, when using the Deutsche Post (esp. after privatisation)?

Comment: @DaleM Except that in court filings for all other courts the date of filing in when it is received by the court.